# Add class to timezone select box in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

By doing `<?php $this->load->helper('date'); echo timezone_menu('UM8'); ?>` I can get a bunch
of helpful timezone options in a select box from CI which generated as:

```
<select name="timezones">
   <option value="UM12">(UTC -12:00) Baker/Howland Island</option>
   <option value="UM11">(UTC -11:00) Samoa Time Zone, Niue</option>
   ...
</select>
```

However, I want to add a class (for example, `<select name="timezones" class="form-control">`) to that select box to inherit style from Bootstrap3. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter sets the class(es) for the select element.

```
timezone_menu('UM8', 'form-control');
```

This is covered in the [CI Date Helper documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html)